# What's This Squishy Replacement Laptop Pad?

Tags: laptop-repair

When I bought a new laptop, it came with several different replacement parts. I was familiar with all of them except for 1 (which came in a set of 2). It's brown, squishy, slightly sticky, and has plastic covers on both ends (1 cover is blue, the other is clear). Here's a pic:

[image: two square pads that came with laptop]

What is this thing named and what's it used for?

Comment: How big are they?

Comment: @fixer1234 They're about an inch square, with about 1/6 inch depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like either thermal pads or feet.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a soft pad to raise the laptop off a hard surface, without scratching the surface.  Makes better ventilation, the hard laptop parts scratch the surface less, etc.  One side is glue, the other soft but resilient.